# What nuance does the `当` represent?

Tags: word-requests, word

In the following sentences:

```
 有一天他会当医生
 有一天我会当经理
```

what does the `当` mean? I think this means something like `One day she would become a doctor`. However, what kind of nuances does `当` include? Is it `would be`, `would become`, `possible`, or `want to`, or something others? How probable does the author think the noun after `当` occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`当` is necessary here, it means `work as; serve as; be`.

```
有一天    他  会    当          医生
One day   he  will  work as     a doctor.
```

As you see, without `当`, the sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is NOT whether I have to use `当` or not; what I want to ask is what kind of nuance it includes. In the sentence, how probable will he work as a doctor?

Comment: @Gardecolo `当` has nothing to do with the probability, the sentence is just `He will be a doctor`. You can use some other words to emphasize the probability such as `肯定`, `百分之百`, `一定` before `会`, or weaken the probability by `可能`, `也许`.

Answer (score 0):

In general,当 have two usages(and I think the understand you provided is right and integrity,I just need to give you some example) :)
1.## become, be ## 
我当医生了。 Here,当is represent become, It is the present tense(the tense is related to '了',have nothing to do with 当)
2## would become, would be ##
有一天我会当医生.  Cause of '有一天', 当 at here means would become,that is to say,he is not a doctor now,it is a wish,a hope.
3.## when ##
当天晴的时候我就去散步。 I will go for a walk when it is sunny.Here,当means when ,it is  a time prep.
4.## face,confront  ##
你不该当着他的面责备他。 You should't blame him in front of him.  当 at here is also a prep.
For the question you asked'How probable does the author think the noun after 当 occur?'   有一天我会当医生。(I will become a doctor one day), the noun(医生or any other jobs) would happen nothing,it is the wish the speaker have, whether his dream could come true is depend on himself.

Comment: I am sorry the form is a

Comment: I am sorry the form is disorder,it was not like this when I edit them.  :(